# jquery .text() or .html() not working

Tags: jquery

I am dynamically generating a div and want to change its content via html()/text(), but its not working.

Here's the code:

```
var div = '<div class="ps_album"><img alt="" src="images/1px.gif" class="thmb"><div class="ps_desc"><h2>title</h2></div></div>';

$(div).find('.ps_desc').html('<h1>Hello</h1>');
$(div).appendTo('body');
```

in above code, the 3rd line i.e.

```
$(div).find('.ps_desc').html('<h1>Hello</h1>');
```

not working.. why??

Comment: There is a jquery bug an older version, the fast time situation a failure variable there are no results to use html (jquery) is not working, try to use pure javascript is works fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that you're re-evaluating `$(div)`.  The first line that operates on the not-yet-added DOM fragment **does not update the string value of "div"**.  Thus, the second time you create `$(div)` you start back over with the original fragment!

Try this:

```
 $(div).find('.ps_desc').html('<h1>Hello World</h1>').end().appendTo($('body'));
```

The jQuery `.end()` method "pops" the effect of the preceding `.find()` call, so in this case it gets you back to the original point of navigation, which is the fragment you're building from the string.  The subsequent call to `.appendTo()` therefore will act on the outer `<div>` you've built, and so that *should* do the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(div).appendTo('body');
$('body').find('.ps_desc').html('<h1>Hello</h1>');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(div).appendTo('body');
$('.ps_desc').html('<h1>Hello</h1>');
```

UPDATE:

A working demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/nbF2H/4/

Answer (score 0):

You should reverse the order i.e.

```
$(div).appendTo('body');
$("body div").find('.ps_desc').html('<h1>Hello</h1>');
```

find and html methods works on elements inside DOM. Unless you append your HTML string to DOM these jquery methods will not work.

Option II

```
var div = $('<div class="ps_album"><img alt="" src="images/1px.gif" class="thmb"><div class="ps_desc"><h2>title</h2></div></div>');

$(div).appendTo('body');
$(div).find('.ps_desc').html('<h1>Hello</h1>');
```

Comment: @Chinmayee option II won't work, because that second call to `$(div)` will re-create the fragment from the same old string value.

Comment: @Pointy that is working check here:http://jsfiddle.net/nbF2H/8/ vs original: http://jsfiddle.net/nbF2H/

Comment: div already contains a jQuery object, so you don't need to $(div), just div. And second I would make it more clear by doing `$div = $(...); $div.appendTo('body').find('.ps_desc').html('<h1>Hello world</h1>');`

Comment: @Chinmayee - oh yes I see now; you convert the string to a jQuery object initially.  Sorry for the mistake!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').append('<div class="ps_album"><img alt="" src="images/1px.gif" class="thmb"><div class="ps_desc"><h2>title</h2></div></div>')
         .find('.ps_desc')
         .html('<h1>Hello World</h1>');
```

[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/jf9fd/)

Answer (score 0):

Today I am presenting on `improvements to security note templates`

This is an example of `XSS vulnerability :`

```
$(div).appendTo('body');
$("body div").find('.ps_desc').html('<h1></h1>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are accessing the correct id.

If you are using ASP.NET, it could be because ASP.NET changes the id names, if you add "runat="server".

Try accessing it by using the class name instead and see if it works.

```
    <td id="mytd" class="myclass" runat="server"></td>
    $('.myclass').html()
    $('.myclass').text()
```